# Is there an easy way to detect *any* (and all) user activity?

Tags: delphi

If the user interacts with my app in any way at all I want to restart a force logoff timer.

Any menu item, any button clicked (not sure about just click on the form).

Is there an easy way to detect that the user is still "active"?

Comment: Use TApplication.OnMessage and react to input messages only

Comment: that would also capture mouse moving over the window. That's hardly interaction.
So the question is - user interacting with application or with computer ?

Comment: @Arioch I guess you'd ignore away mouse moves if the app was inactive.

Comment: Would this Stackoverflow answer help?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2212823/how-to-detect-inactive-user

Comment: @Dean +1 and I will award you the answer if you post that as an answer

Comment: @DeanRoberson, sorry I awarded, just to close the question. I owe you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This component is exactly what you are looking for. It is called ETimer and can be found [here](http://www.delphigroups.info/2/80/471635.html)

Basically just put the timer on a form and set its interval for like 1000 ms, then in the timer event check the Snooze property of the timer, if the snooze property is greater that 60000 (1 min) then you know that the app has had no user interaction for 1 min.

It pretty easy to use but let me know if you get stuck.