# SCCM: detect if user is present by checking keypress mousemove, is it possible?

Tags: sccm

I don't know much about SCCM but I wonder if it is possible to guess if a user is in front of his computer by monitoring the datetime of last keypress or mouse move.
This doesn't need to be very accurate (say 5 minutes precision).

Could SCCM do this natively ?

if yes what should I install on clients (or what settings should I alter) ?

if no, could I create my own agent and integrate with SCCM ?
[C# - Detect time of last user interaction with the OS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1037595/c-sharp-detect-time-of-last-user-interaction-with-the-os)

if still no then I suppose SCCM is not the right tool to do this. So what shall I do ? Create my own agent. Run it at startup (as service?) on every PC. Periodically probe a listener (asp.net page) that will record it in database ?

I need to check availability for 2000 users.

How does Skype Enterprise check for status of user ? Could I query some kind of windows service to get the same information ?

Answer (score 0):

`Could SCCM do this natively ?`

No.

`if no, could I create my own agent and integrate with SCCM ?`

Yes, I don't know what version of sccm you're using, but you can integrate pretty tightly with sccm using their [SDK](http://goo.gl/ZTmVq). Most of it is capable using managed code, although if you want to use the dlls that are unmanaged, you can try the type lib converter that comes with visual studio, I have had success converting their TSEnvironment.dll unmanaged library to a managed one. Creating your own agent might be quite a bit of work for what you want to accomplish, you might be able to get by with just communicating with the client or server when needed.

Answer (score 0):

You could use custom "hardware" inventory (MOF), populating the idle information and reporting it back to SCCM that way. The information from the custom inventory retrieval ends up in the SCCM database, so you could report on that however you wanted.

You can get the user input idle like this:
[How to detect inactive user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2212823/how-to-detect-inactive-user/2212854#2212854)
 - It's a windows API, so you should be able to find code examples in the managed/scripting language of your choice.

Then, write that information to WMI.

Create an SCCM package to run on a schedule (every 5 minutes?), which runs this script, then runs the SendSchedule.exe.

It might not be the most efficient way to do it, but that's a potential solution utilizing SCCM to transfer the data. You could also use a web service, and just create a method to write the data into a database - it would probably be more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

SCCM can deploy applications based on whether a user is logged in or not. For that many users having SCCM check that frequently wouldn't be very efficient. SCCM isn't the best for Real Time information.

Tanium may be a product worth looking into. Less functionality as SCCM but able to monitor in "basically" real time.