# GetLastInputInfo and GetTickCount are not consistent with each other

Tags: python, windows, pywin32

I am trying to work out how long, approximately, the current user has been idle (e.g. like [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203384/how-to-tell-when-windows-is-inactive)), from Python on a Windows machine.

To do that, I figure I need to compare the result of [GetLastInputInfo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646302(VS.85).aspx) with the result of 
[GetTickCount](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724408(v=vs.85).aspx). The results should be in milliseconds.

(I am expecting roll-over problems every 49.7 days, but I will solve that later.)

My code is straightforward:

```
import win32api

last_active = win32api.GetLastInputInfo()
now = win32api.GetTickCount()
elapsed_milliseconds = (now - last_active)

print(last_active, now, elapsed_milliseconds)
```

I expect to get two similar large numbers, and a difference of a few hundred milliseconds.

Instead, I get results like:

```
3978299058 -316668238 -4294967296
```

and

```
3978316717 -316650501 -4294967218
```

Between runs, they are both changing by roughly the same amount, but there is a large constant offset between them that I am not expecting.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the numbers more closely, this is a signed/unsigned mismatch.

3978299058 = 0xED2006B2

-316668238 (in two's complement) = 0xED2006B2

3978316717 = 0xED204BAD

-316650501 (in two's complement) = 0xED204BFB

So the times are consistent, it's just that `win32.GetTickCount` is interpreting the tick count as a signed 32-bit integer whereas `win32.GetLastInputInfo` is interpreting it as unsigned.

(Specifically, `GetLastInputInfo` is using `PyLong_FromUnsignedLong` whereas `GetTickCount` casts the `DWORD` to a `long` and then calls `Py_BuildValue`.  You might want to consider filing a bug, since the tick count *should* be an unsigned value.)

Comment: I understand the theory, but inspecting the pywin32 code (win32apimodule.cpp:1671) it says "return PyLong_FromUnsignedLong(lii.dwTime);" which looks right.

Comment: Yep, I should have looked at the actual numbers more closely.  The problem is simply that one value is being returned as unsigned and the other as signed.

Comment: I have filed a [bug report](https://sourceforge.net/p/pywin32/bugs/718/). Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

ONce again, posting to Stack Overflow is the quickest way to find the answer to my own problem.

It is a roll-over problem.

The two values are very similar when they are mod 2<sup>32</sup>.

GetTickCount64 would be a better call, but it is not included in win32API.

Comment: I don't think using GetTickCount64 would help, since according to the documentation, GetLastInputInfo returns only a 32-bit tick count.